# Geometric realization of simplicial sets

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I wonder if we can construct some different geometric realizations?

In the current construction, $n$-cells of geometric realization are in one-to-one correspondence with non-degenerate simplices in $X_n$, which is due to the equivalence relation given by $$(f^*(x), t)\sim (x, f_*(t)), x\in X_n, t\in \Delta^m$$ for every
morphism $f : [m]\to [n]$ in $\Delta$

(Recall the geometric realization is defined by $|X_*|= (\bigsqcup_{n\ge0} X_n\times \Delta^n)/\sim$).

I think if we drop the equivalence relation, we can get a new CW-complex, where $n$-cells of construction are in one-to-one correspondence with simplices in $X_n$.(Am I right? I am not very sure, but it seems that works)

Also, is there a specific reason/motivation for the current construction of the geometric realization? Why do we require $n$-cells of geometric realization are in one-to-one correspondence with non-degenerate simplices in $X_n$?

Comment: If You drop the equivalence relation, then You always get disjoint sums of simplices $\Delta^k$, so there's no way to obtain spaces with interesting homotopy type (e.g. connected and non-contractible). On the other hand, one of reasonable requirements for geometric realization is to have all homotopy types in its image (up to weak homotopy equivalence).

Comment: @pmp thanks, but how is that related to the non-degenerated simplices? Is non-degenerated simplices very important. Or is that just because the degenerated simplices make no contribution to $|X_*|$?

Answer (score 0):

The geometric realization of a simplicial set is only unique up to (topological) isomorphism. There is no overriding reason to define as you do above. The definition of geometric realization you give is chosen firstly so that

1) It is functorial in simplicial maps $X_\bullet\rightarrow Y_\bullet$.

2) It defines a left adjoint to the singular set functor $Top\xrightarrow{S}sSet$ definedby $SY_n=Map(\Delta^n,Y)$.

and also so that

3) For 'nice' classes of simplicial sets it will take values in 'nice' classes of topological spaces.

In particular the geometric realisation $|-|$ depends on the choice of the standard topological simplices $\Delta^n$, the definition of the singular set functor $S$ and how we want it to interact with certain classes of simplicial sets and spaces. It is "defined" as above by many texts simply because it is the most convenient possible definition.

Indeed a similar definition is that of the *fat* geometric realization, given by

$||X_\bullet||=\bigsqcup_{n\geq 0} X_n\times \Delta^n /\left[(d_ix,t)\sim (x,d^it)\right]$

In particular the fat geometric realization does not throw away the degenerate simplices. There is a natural map

$\alpha:||X_\bullet||\rightarrow |X_\bullet|$,

and if $X_\bullet$ is *good*, that is, if each degeneracy map $s_i:X_{n-1}\rightarrow  X_n$ for each $n$ is a closed cofibration, then $\alpha$ is a homotopy equivalence. It has other nice properties. If $f_\bullet:X_\bullet\rightarrow Y_\bullet$ is a levelwise homotopy equivalence then $||f_\bullet||$ is a homotopy equivalence whilse $|f|$ need not be. See for example Segal's paper 'Categories and Cohomology theories'.